# Pytorch: How to find accuracy for Multi Label Classification?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am using vgg16, where number of classes is 3, and I can have multiple labels predicted for a data point.

`vgg16 = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
vgg16.classifier[6]= nn.Linear(4096, 3)`

using loss function : `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()`

I am able to find find accuracy in case of a single label problem, as

```
 `images, labels = data
 images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
 labels = Encode(labels)
 outputs = vgg16(images)
 _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
 total += labels.size(0)
 correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
 acc = (100 * correct / total)`
```

How can I find accuracy for multi label classification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, `vgg16` is returning raw logits. So here's what you can do:

```
labels = Encode(labels)  # torch.Size([N, C]) e.g. tensor([[1., 1., 1.]])
outputs = vgg16(images)  # torch.Size([N, C])
outputs = torch.sigmoid(outputs)  # torch.Size([N, C]) e.g. tensor([[0., 0.5, 0.]])
outputs[outputs >= 0.5] = 1
accuracy = (outputs == labels).sum()/(N*C)*100
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are considering accuracy in terms of total corrected labels**, then you should also assign 0 to outputs less than a threshold in contrast to accepted answer.

See following code:

```
labels = Encode(labels) ## for example, labels = [[1,0,1],[0,1,1]]
N,C = labels.shape

outputs = vgg16(images)
outputs = torch.sigmoid(outputs) ## for example, outputs = [[0.75,0.4,0.9],[0.2,0.6,0.8]]

## for threshold of 0.5 accuracy should be 100% while from accepted answer you will get 66.67% so

outputs[outputs >= 0.5] = 1
outputs[outputs < 0.5] = 0 ## assign 0 label to those with less than 0.5

accuracy = (outputs == labels).sum() / (N*C) * 100
```